# how to print the value of table along with their field name

Tags: php, mysql

this is my table:

```
student_name  father_name  sub1  sub2

  kunwar        Siyaram    20     40
```

I want to print the value of table along with their field name as:

```
Student_name : kunwar
father_name : Siyaram
sub1  : 20
sub2  : 40
```

**Query**

```
$select = mysql_query("select * from 2mcom where father_name='Siyaram'");
```

Comment: close vote....easily googalable!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no effort

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this would be static, you can do this way:

```
while (false != ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)))
  foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    echo "$key: $value<br />";
```

Comment: its working but with some problem its like 0: Kunwar Singh
student_name: Kunwar Singh
1: Siyaram
father_name: Siyaram

Comment: use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`

Comment: i dont want "0: Kunwar Singh" , i want only "student_name: Kunwar Singh "

Comment: Okay, in that case, give it as: `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

Comment: @AmritaGupta Can you post your full code? Looks like you have left one of the `)`

Comment: i want the value of $value in input box. when i am doing it "$value" is coming ,not its actual value.

Comment: Yes.. It will give the value from the DB only.. It won't be others...

Comment: Yes... Is it possible to mail the code or something, I can help you with it.

Comment: Sir,  Ur email id please......?